# Appropriate Data Structure?

Tags: asp.net, data-structures, enums

I have a Cards class - each Card is one of four Colors.  Each Color has interesting data associated with it - like hex# and a number representation.  I was originally going to use enums but I don't know how to include these other two properties.

I'd like to be able to reference the Colors like Colors.Red and Colors.Blue, and the data behind each color via Colors.Red.Hex or Colors.Red.Id.  What's the appropriate data structure here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a class called Color with properties called Hex and Id. Then have static Properties that return the static colors you want: (this is in C#)

```
public class Color
{
    public string Hex { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public static Color Red
    {
        get
        {
            return new Color 
            {
                Hex = "DD0000",
                Id = 1
            };
        }
    }

    public static Color Blue
    {
        get
        {
            return new Color
            {
                Hex = "hex for blue",
                Id = 2
            };
        }
    }
}
```

If you dont want to be able to create custome colors, make the Color constructor private.

Comment: Thanks lockstock.  How would I be able to define the Hex and Id from those get statements?  Say I want to create Red / 1 / DD0000 for the whole solution to see, how would you do that?  And - what is this called?  Are we instantiating new objects from within a class?  Any special terminology here that I can read up on?

Comment: see my updated answer. I'm not sure what the name of this pattern is, if you had a private construtor I think it's called the Factory pattern

Answer (score 0):

All that stuff is built in:

```
// using System.Drawing;

Color MyColor = Color.Red;

int Value = MyColor.ToArgb();

byte R = MyColor.R;
byte G = MyColor.G;
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  That was for the sake of simplicity - I'm not actually dealing with colors.  I'm dealing with Cards that have a Status of anything from 1 to 10, each Status having a few attributes.

Comment: @RobVious Are the status attributes fixed? or can they vary?